# Reply-To Queue is not updating in IBM MQ while putting message type as request

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, jmstemplate

```
jmsTemplate.sendAndReceive("Queue2", session -> {
                TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage();
                msg.setText(message);
                msg.setJMSReplyTo(config.getReplyQ());      //Not updated but auto generated queue updated
                msg.setJMSCorrelationID("asd_123584_lkj");  //Updated in Destination Queue
                msg.setJMSType("MQSTR");

                System.out.println("Message : "+msg);

                return msg;
            });


public Destination getReplyQ() throws JMSException {
        MQQueue replyToQ = new MQQueue(queueManager, replyQueue);
        Destination replyTo = (Destination) replyToQ;
        return replyTo;
    }
```

[image: IBM MQ message]

I read some articles that says using JMS will update the RFH but not MQMD and this Reply-To Queue is part of MQMD and I didn't find the right class to update the MQMD header and send the message to MQ and update the reply-to queue.

Comment: Did you check / log what `config.getReplyQ()` returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jmsTemplate.send(config.getQ(), session -> {
            TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage();
            msg.setText(message);
            msg.setJMSReplyTo(config.getReplyQ());
            msg.setJMSCorrelationID("asd_123584_lkj");
            System.out.println("Message : " + msg);
            return msg;
        });
```

Above method will set the JMSReplyTo.

[Here the definition of sendAndReceive is present which stated that "a temporary queue is created as part of this operation and is set in the JMSReplyTO header of the message"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html)

And to ignore the RFH2 header [setTargetClient(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/8.0?topic=objects-targclient) can be used like below:

```
public Destination getQ() throws JMSException {
        MQQueue replyToQ = new MQQueue(queueManager, queues);
        replyToQ.setTargetClient(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);
        Destination rt = (Destination) replyToQ;
        return rt;
    }
```